# Installing packages on Microsoft R Open fails

Tags: r, linux, package, install.packages, microsoft-r

I've never had any issues installing packages on R, but I always have issues installing packages on Microsoft R Open. For example, I attempted to install tidyverse. I received many errors, listed below:

```
> Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation
> failed for package ‘colorspace’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/colorspace’
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘colorspace’
> had non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘mnormt’ ...
> ** package ‘mnormt’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mnormt’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/mnormt’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘mnormt’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘fansi’ ...
> ** package ‘fansi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fansi’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/fansi’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘fansi’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘utf8’ ...
> ** package ‘utf8’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘utf8’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/utf8’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘utf8’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘backports’ ...
> ** package ‘backports’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘backports’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/backports’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘backports’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘xfun’ ...
> ** package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** R
> ** inst
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> ** help
> *** installing help indices
> ** building package indices
> ** installing vignettes
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
> * DONE (xfun)
> * installing *source* package ‘glue’ ...
> ** package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glue’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/glue’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘glue’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
> ** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘digest’ ...
> ** package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘digest’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/digest’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘digest’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘lazyeval’ ...
> ** package ‘lazyeval’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lazyeval’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/lazyeval’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘lazyeval’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘mime’ ...
> ** package ‘mime’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mime’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/mime’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘mime’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
> ** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found Using PKG_CFLAGS=   ------------------------- ANTICONF
> ERROR ---------------------------   Configuration failed because
> openssl was not found. Try installing:   * deb: libssl-dev (Debian,
> Ubuntu, etc)
> * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
> * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
> * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX) If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a
> openssl.pc file. If pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR
> and LIB_DIR manually via:   R CMD INSTALL
> --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
> --------------------------------------------------------------------   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/openssl’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero
> exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘clipr’ ...
> ** package ‘clipr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** R
> ** inst
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> ** help
> *** installing help indices
> ** building package indices
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
> * DONE (clipr)
> * installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
> ** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked checking for R_HOME... /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R checking for
> R... /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/R checking for
> endianness... little checking for R >= 3.1.0 for C++11 use... yes
> checking for R < 3.4.0 for CXX1X flag use... no checking for cat...
> /bin/cat /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make:
> not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval:
> make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1:
> eval: make: not found /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config:
> 1: eval: make: not found
> /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.0/lib64/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not
> found checking for local ICUDT_DIR... icu61/data checking for gcc...
> no checking for cc... no checking for cl.exe... no configure: error:
> in `/tmp/RtmpO4zIl6/R.INSTALL1f4a655950bf/stringi': configure: error:
> no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH See `config.log' for more
> details ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/stringi’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero
> exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘yaml’ ...
> ** package ‘yaml’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘yaml’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/yaml’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘yaml’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘base64enc’ ...
> ** package ‘base64enc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘base64enc’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/base64enc’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘base64enc’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
> ** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs sh: 1: make: not found Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rlang’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rlang’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘digest’, ‘rlang’ are not
> available for package ‘testthat’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/testthat’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘testthat’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘colorspace’ is not available
> for package ‘munsell’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/munsell’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘munsell’ had non-zero
> exit status ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package
> ‘plyr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/plyr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘plyr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available for
> package ‘psych’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/psych’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘psych’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for
> package ‘bindrcpp’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/bindrcpp’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘bindrcpp’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘fansi’, ‘rlang’, ‘utf8’ are
> not available for package ‘pillar’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/pillar’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘pillar’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘mime’ is not available for
> package ‘markdown’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/markdown’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘markdown’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘digest’, ‘Rcpp’ are not
> available for package ‘htmltools’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/htmltools’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘htmltools’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘backports’ is not available
> for package ‘rprojroot’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rprojroot’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rprojroot’ had
> non-zero exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘tinytex’ ...
> ** package ‘tinytex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** R
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> ** help
> *** installing help indices
> ** building package indices
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
> * DONE (tinytex) ERROR: dependency ‘rlang’ is not available for package ‘hms’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/hms’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘hms’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘mime’, ‘openssl’ are not
> available for package ‘httr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/httr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘httr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘glue’, ‘stringi’ are not
> available for package ‘stringr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/stringr’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero
> exit status ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package
> ‘xml2’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/xml2’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘xml2’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘testthat’ is not available for
> package ‘processx’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/processx’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘processx’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘plyr’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘stringr’ are
> not available for package ‘reshape2’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/reshape2’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘reshape2’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘plyr’, ‘munsell’, ‘Rcpp’ are
> not available for package ‘scales’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/scales’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘scales’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘stringr’ is not available for
> package ‘selectr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/selectr’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘selectr’ had non-zero
> exit status ERROR: dependency ‘stringr’ is not available for package
> ‘evaluate’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/evaluate’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘evaluate’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘stringr’, ‘Rcpp’ are not
> available for package ‘lubridate’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/lubridate’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘lubridate’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘pillar’, ‘rlang’ are not
> available for package ‘tibble’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/tibble’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘tibble’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘tibble’ is not available for
> package ‘cellranger’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/cellranger’
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘cellranger’
> had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘processx’ is not available
> for package ‘callr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/callr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘callr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’ are not
> available for package ‘forcats’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/forcats’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘forcats’ had non-zero
> exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘digest’, ‘lazyeval’, ‘plyr’,
> ‘reshape2’, ‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’ are not available for package
> ‘ggplot2’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/ggplot2’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero
> exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’ are not available
> for package ‘purrr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/purrr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘purrr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘tibble’, ‘hms’ are
> not available for package ‘readr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/readr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘readr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘xml2’, ‘httr’, ‘selectr’ are
> not available for package ‘rvest’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rvest’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rvest’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘tibble’, ‘hms’ are
> not available for package ‘feather’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/feather’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘feather’ had non-zero
> exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘evaluate’, ‘markdown’, ‘stringr’,
> ‘yaml’ are not available for package ‘knitr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/knitr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘knitr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘glue’, ‘purrr’, ‘rlang’,
> ‘Rcpp’ are not available for package ‘tidyselect’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/tidyselect’
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘tidyselect’
> had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘forcats’, ‘hms’, ‘Rcpp’,
> ‘readr’, ‘tibble’ are not available for package ‘haven’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/haven’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘haven’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘cellranger’, ‘Rcpp’,
> ‘tibble’ are not available for package ‘readxl’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/readxl’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘readxl’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘knitr’, ‘yaml’, ‘htmltools’,
> ‘evaluate’, ‘base64enc’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘mime’, ‘stringr’ are not
> available for package ‘rmarkdown’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rmarkdown’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘bindrcpp’, ‘glue’, ‘Rcpp’,
> ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyselect’ are not available for package ‘dplyr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/dplyr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘dplyr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘callr’, ‘rlang’, ‘rmarkdown’
> are not available for package ‘reprex’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/reprex’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘reprex’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘dplyr’, ‘glue’, ‘purrr’,
> ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyselect’ are not available for package ‘dbplyr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/dbplyr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘dplyr’, ‘glue’, ‘purrr’,
> ‘Rcpp’, ‘rlang’, ‘stringi’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyselect’ are not available
> for package ‘tidyr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/tidyr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘tidyr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘dplyr’, ‘plyr’, ‘psych’,
> ‘reshape2’, ‘stringr’, ‘tidyr’ are not available for package ‘broom’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/broom’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘broom’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘dplyr’, ‘purrr’,
> ‘tibble’, ‘tidyr’, ‘rlang’ are not available for package ‘modelr’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/modelr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘modelr’ had
> non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘broom’, ‘dplyr’, ‘dbplyr’,
> ‘forcats’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘haven’, ‘hms’, ‘httr’, ‘lubridate’, ‘modelr’,
> ‘purrr’, ‘readr’, ‘readxl’, ‘reprex’, ‘rlang’, ‘rvest’, ‘stringr’,
> ‘tibble’, ‘tidyr’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
> * removing ‘/home/myFilePath/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/tidyverse’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had
> non-zero exit status
> 
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/tmp/RtmpDGk37A/downloaded_packages’
```

In the past, my solution has been to give up and continue using regular R, but I'd like to try to take advantage of MRO's multithreading.

Again, using the simple `install.packages("tidyverse")` command works in R. What do I have to do differently in MRO?

Comment: You need to include full error messages from R terminal. One single line doesn't help

Comment: How about restarting MRO then running: `install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")`

Comment: I agree with @Tung, what errors do you receive? Also, I installed `tidyverse` yesterday with no issues

Comment: @Tung unforutnately, `install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")` did not work. I updated my question to include the whole terminal output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors told you that you didn't have necessary tools (`make`, `gcc`) for building R packages in Linux

```
libs sh: 1: make: not found 
...
no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

You will need to install [`r-base-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/r-base-dev) to get those

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

See more:

- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html
- https://packages.debian.org/sid/r-base-dev
- [R package installation in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784182/r-package-installation-in-linux)

Comment: This is a pretty strange claim. As far as I know neither gcc nor make are installed with r-base-dev. I'm pretty sure that both are part of the basic GNU/Linux set of tools. I don't read those messages as saying that `make` was not found; rather than `make` was not finding stuff that it expected in the locations it was trying.