# Ubuntu installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, ubuntu

Hello I am using R with Ubuntu 18.0.4 and having trouble to install packages. I have installed

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

but still it produces the following error

> installing *source* package ‘labelled’ ...
>    package ‘labelled’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>    R
>    inst
>    preparing package for lazy loading
>   Warning: S3 methods ‘[.fun_list’, ‘[.grouped_df’, ‘all.equal.tbl_df’, ‘anti_join.data.frame’, ‘anti_join.tbl_df’, ‘arrange.data.frame’, ‘arrange.default’, ‘arrange.grouped_df’, ‘arrange.tbl_df’, ‘arrange_.data.frame’, ‘arrange_.tbl_df’, ‘as.data.frame.grouped_df’, ‘as.data.frame.rowwise_df’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_cube’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_df’, ‘as.table.tbl_cube’, ‘as.tbl.data.frame’, ‘as.tbl.tbl’, ‘as.tbl_cube.array’, ‘as.tbl_cube.data.frame’, ‘as.tbl_cube.matrix’, ‘as.tbl_cube.table’, ‘as_data_frame.grouped_df’, ‘as_data_frame.tbl_cube’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_cube’, ‘auto_copy.tbl_df’, ‘cbind.grouped_df’, ‘collapse.data.frame’, ‘collect.data.frame’, ‘common_by.NULL’, ‘common_by.character’, ‘common_by.default’, ‘common_by.list’, ‘compute.data.frame’, ‘copy_to.DBIConnection’, ‘copy_to.src_local’, ‘default_missing.data.frame’, ‘default_missing.default’, �� [... truncated]
>   Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
>     shared object ‘dplyr.so’ not found
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘labelled’
>    removing ‘/home/sami/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/labelled’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpZbHxk1/downloaded_packages’

Warning message:

> In install.packages("labelled") :
>     installation of package ‘labelled’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: We would certainly need more of the error message to provide any help.

Comment: I suspect you have the same problem as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51364823/786542

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the following libraries: **libxml2-dev, libssl-dev and libcurl4-openssl-dev**. Try to install them all using the apt command.

Greetings!