# unable to install mclust package R in ubuntu

Tags: r, mclust

I tried to install mclust package R in RStudio using different ways

```
install.packages("mclust")
devtools::install_github("cran/mclust")
biocLite('mclust')
```

but I get this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘mclust’ ...
** package ‘mclust’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-Oe9izK/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-Oe9izK/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c mclust.f -o mclust.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-Oe9izK/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c mclustaddson.f -o mclustaddson.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o mclust.so init.o mclust.o mclustaddson.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'mclust.so' failed
make: *** [mclust.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mclust’
* removing ‘/home/mohammadi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/mclust’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mclust’ had non-zero exit status
```

I ran this command `sudo apt-get install gfortran` to install gfortran, but it said `gfortran is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1)`.

Can anyone help me out? Many thanks!

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51364823/786542

Comment: Even more relevant, though same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6302209/6646912 (the important line in your output which hints on the problem is `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran`)